# Cannot open hw:0,0 default audio device

Tags: audio, alsa

Hello I am trying to setup icecast streaming server.

Previously I used Loopback devices and it worked fine. But Loopback devices does not have a mixer so I cant play two things at once is you see what I mean.

I know the default audio device can do this.

So I change the audio device in icecast-alsa.xml from "hw:Loopback,1,0" to "hw:0,0"

I also tried

"hw:0,1"
"default"

But none of these work Im getting the error:

Could not open device Directory or file does not exist.

It would be great if someone could help me.